# local query scope for the array attribute

Tags: laravel, filter, scope, model, eloquent

**I want to filter evaluations with a query scope, but in my model I have a fillable which is an array and it is from there that I want to filter**

I have an attribute in my model that is a goal (array) where the roles assigned to that evaluation are saved for each evaluation.

```
protected $fillable = [
    'id',
    'title',
    'description',
    'editable_before',
    'available_start',
    'available_end',
    'client_id',
    'meta',
];

protected $casts = [
    'meta' => 'array',
];
```

this is an evaluation that tests to show you

```
"id": 90,
"title": "inquiry Irvin Giovanni",
"description": "description encuesta irvin",
"instructions": null,
"editable_before": null,
"available_start": "2017-11-13 00:00:00",
"available_end": "2017-11-13 00:00:00",
"client_id": 9,
"meta": {
  "userTypes": [
      {
        "role": "COACH",
        "level": "KIN"
      },
      {
        "role": "ADMIN",
        "level": "SEC"
      },
      {
        "role": "PROF",
        "level": "SEC"
      }
    ]
}
```

I want to filter the evaluation depending on the type of role that the query scope receives

idea:

```
public function scopeRole($query, $role)
{
    return $query->where('meta.userTypes', '=', $role);
}
```

**the idea is that in the parameter of the query scope function could pass "ADMIN", "PROF", "COACH" and I return the evaluations that have a certain parameter**

Comment: Is it possible to move the user types out into their own database table. Check out https://github.com/caffeinated/shinobi it's a user role system which is super simple to implement and use. $user->assignRole('ADMIN') and then if($user->isRole('ADMIN')). You could then change the scopeRole to join to the user_roles table and it would be much better and much faster then trying to parse json/array in a database query

Comment: How is `meta` defined in the database?

Comment: yes @Camilo, it's a column in my bd of type json

Comment: I think you can use `whereRaw("JSON_CONTAINS(meta->userTypes, $json)")`, where `$json` is `{"role": "COACH", "level": "KIN"}` for example.